# multiple singleton beans referencing the same class

Tags: java, spring, singleton, inversion-of-control

I have a java class lets say 'class1' which basically holds a ConcurrentHashMap (to be used as a cache) and some functions to update and remove the entries in the map.This class is not designed to be a singleton class.
I was having a discussion with a colleague, but couldnt really decide due to a couple of posts i read on the internet.I am asking if it is okay to do this-

```
<bean id="reqrespCacheMgr1" class="gravity.applications.RFQService.reqrespgtwy.utility.ReqRespCacheManager" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
<bean id="reqrespCacheMgr2" class="gravity.applications.RFQService.reqrespgtwy.utility.ReqRespCacheManager" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
<bean id="reqrespCacheMgr3" class="gravity.applications.RFQService.reqrespgtwy.utility.ReqRespCacheManager" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
```

I am basically trying to create 3 singleton instances of the same class..I think it doesnt really spoil the meaning of singleton-ness because we are talking about singleton scope in the spring bean factory context and not the class loader context.. I know there are alternate ways to do this.. Like having 3 concurrenthash maps in the same class and using only one singleton bean reference ,there by trying to create update and remove methods for 3 maps in the same class.

I hope i didnt make it confusing but all i wanna know is which is a good approach.I am afraid im making an improper use of design patterns..

Let me know if the question is unclear

Comment: I don't see any problem with this solution. Does it work when you try it? Does it do wat you want it to do?

Comment: i still havent got there..I am trying to lay it all down before coding . I am sure it works,just concerned about the usage

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need not a singleton but prototype

```
<bean id="reqrespCacheMgr" class="gravity.applications.RFQService.reqrespgtwy.utility.ReqRespCacheManager" scope="prototype" />

class B1 {
   @Autowire
   ReqRespCacheManager cacheManager;
}

class B2 {
   @Autowire
   ReqRespCacheManager cacheManager;
}

class B3 {
   @Autowire
   ReqRespCacheManager cacheManager;
}
```

All 3 beans will get a new instance of ReqRespCacheManager

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me, as long as you only need to use those 3 instances for the entire lifecycle of your application.  Are you aware that autowiring a single property wont work for this type?
You will need to use @Qualifier to assign a specific instance into your application beans:

```
public class FooBean {
   @Inject
   @Qualifier("reqrespCacheMgr3")
   ReqRespCacheManager cacheManager;
}
```

Alternatively, you can collect all three into a single bean by injecting a List component of your type.

```
@Inject
List<ReqRespCacheManager> caches;
```

Hope that helps!  Good luck, and dont forget to think 2 steps ahead.